# R.java file - ";" is expected with space in resource name

Tags: java, android, r.java-file

I'm pretty sure I (at least intentionally) haven't done anything to the code in R.java, but I am getting a compiler error, saying that a ";" is expected.
In R there is a line: `public static final int phone number=0x7f0b0061;` where the word `"number"` is red (this is where the error is)

I don't understand why there is a space between phone and number unless I accidentally messed with it.

I tried modifying and deleting the line but the R class just brought it back and gave me the error again. What can I do?

[image: here is a screenshot]

Comment: You can't edit `R.java`. You must find the XML file that is wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The R class gets generated when you build your project. You can't modify it. You probably used

> android:id="@+id/phone number"

Instead of

> android:id="@+id/phone_number"

In one of your layout-files.

Comment: thank you! I see my mistake now in one of my xml files.

Comment: @Mattie Sanseverino  You're welcome. Don't forget to mark to my answer as accepted if it solved your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers